¿Cómo leer archivos de Google Drive con una App en Android?
Descargué los programas propuestos en la documentación de Android para cargar archivos de Google Drive, pero no se ejecutan. Ya tengo Oauth2 y la credencial de la API.
Muestro el código que ya compila y ejecuta pero al parecer No accede a Google Drive, entiendo que se debe acceder a la API Rest de Google Drive; no se si esto se está logrando. He buscado información pero tiene más de 4 años y la API Rest tiene menos tiempo que se actualizó, descontinuando la API de Google Drive.
Quiero descargar imágenes png y vídeos mp4. ¿Alguna orientación por favor? De antemano, gracias.
Permisos en Manifest
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Dependencias en Gradle
    implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1")
    implementation("com.google.http-client:google-http-client-gson:1.26.0")
    implementation("com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.26.0") {
        exclude("org.apache.httpcomponents")
    }
    implementation("com.google.apis:google-api-services-drive:v3-rev136-1.25.0") {
        exclude("org.apache.httpcomponents")
    }
    implementation("com.google.guava:guava:27.0.1-android"){
        exclude("com.google.guava")
    }

    android { packagingOptions { resources.excludes.add("META-INF/*") } }

MainActivity.java
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInClient;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Scope;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.android.http.AndroidHttp;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential;
import com.google.api.services.drive.Drive;
import com.google.api.services.drive.DriveScopes;
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.File;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import java.util.Collections;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_SIGN_IN = 1;
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_OPEN_DOCUMENT = 2;

    private DriveServiceHelper mDriveServiceHelper;
    private String mOpenFileId;

    private EditText mFileTitleEditText;
    private EditText mDocContentEditText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mFileTitleEditText = findViewById(R.id.file_title_edittext);
        mDocContentEditText = findViewById(R.id.doc_content_edittext);

        // Set the onClick listeners for the button bar.
        findViewById(R.id.open_btn).setOnClickListener(view -> openFilePicker());
        findViewById(R.id.create_btn).setOnClickListener(view -> createFile());
        findViewById(R.id.save_btn).setOnClickListener(view -> saveFile());
        findViewById(R.id.query_btn).setOnClickListener(view -> query());
        requestSignIn();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent resultData) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_CODE_SIGN_IN:
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && resultData != null) {
                    handleSignInResult(resultData);
                }
                break;

            case REQUEST_CODE_OPEN_DOCUMENT:
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && resultData != null) {
                    Uri uri = resultData.getData();
                    if (uri != null) {
                        openFileFromFilePicker(uri);
                    }
                }
                break;
        }

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, resultData);
    }

    private void requestSignIn() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Requesting sign-in");
        Toast.makeText(this, "Solicitando sign-in", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        GoogleSignInOptions signInOptions =
                new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                        .requestEmail()
                        .requestScopes(new Scope(DriveScopes.DRIVE_FILE))
                        .build();
        GoogleSignInClient client = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, signInOptions);

        // The result of the sign-in Intent is handled in onActivityResult.
        startActivityForResult(client.getSignInIntent(), REQUEST_CODE_SIGN_IN);
    }

    private void handleSignInResult(Intent result) {
        GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(result)
                .addOnSuccessListener(googleAccount -> {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Signed in as " + googleAccount.getEmail());
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Signed as: "+googleAccount.getEmail(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    // Use the authenticated account to sign in to the Drive service.
                    GoogleAccountCredential credential =
                            GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(
                                    this, Collections.singleton(DriveScopes.DRIVE_FILE));
                    credential.setSelectedAccount(googleAccount.getAccount());
                    Drive googleDriveService =
                            new Drive.Builder(
                                    AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
                                    new GsonFactory(),
                                    credential)
                                    .setApplicationName("Drive API Migration")
                                    .build();

                    // The DriveServiceHelper encapsulates all REST API and SAF functionality.
                    // Its instantiation is required before handling any onClick actions.
                    mDriveServiceHelper = new DriveServiceHelper(googleDriveService);
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(exception -> Log.e(TAG, "Unable to sign in.", exception));
    }

    private void openFilePicker() {
        if (mDriveServiceHelper != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Opening file picker.");

            Intent pickerIntent = mDriveServiceHelper.createFilePickerIntent();

            // The result of the SAF Intent is handled in onActivityResult.
            startActivityForResult(pickerIntent, REQUEST_CODE_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
        }
    }

    private void openFileFromFilePicker(Uri uri) {
        if (mDriveServiceHelper != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Opening " + uri.getPath());

            mDriveServiceHelper.openFileUsingStorageAccessFramework(getContentResolver(), uri)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(nameAndContent -> {
                        String name = nameAndContent.first;
                        String content = nameAndContent.second;

                        mFileTitleEditText.setText(name);
                        mDocContentEditText.setText(content);

                        // Files opened through SAF cannot be modified.
                        setReadOnlyMode();
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(exception ->
                            Log.e(TAG, "Unable to open file from picker.", exception));
        }
    }

    private void createFile() {
        if (mDriveServiceHelper != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Creating a file.");
            Toast.makeText(this, "Creando archivo: ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            mDriveServiceHelper.createFile()
                    .addOnSuccessListener(fileId -> readFile(fileId))
                    .addOnFailureListener(exception ->
                            Toast.makeText(this, "No se puede crear archivo: ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show());
                            //Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't create file.", exception));
        }
    }

    private void readFile(String fileId) {

        if (mDriveServiceHelper != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Reading file " + fileId);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Leyendo archivo: "+fileId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mDriveServiceHelper.readFile(fileId)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(nameAndContent -> {
                        String name = nameAndContent.first;
                        String content = nameAndContent.second;

                        mFileTitleEditText.setText(name);
                        mDocContentEditText.setText(content);

                        setReadWriteMode(fileId);
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(exception ->
                            Toast.makeText(this, "No se puede leer: "+exception, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show());
                            //Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't read file.", exception));
        }
    }

    private void saveFile() {
        if (mDriveServiceHelper != null && mOpenFileId != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Saving " + mOpenFileId);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Salvando "+mOpenFileId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            String fileName = mFileTitleEditText.getText().toString();
            String fileContent = mDocContentEditText.getText().toString();

            mDriveServiceHelper.saveFile(mOpenFileId, fileName, fileContent)
                    .addOnFailureListener(exception ->
                            Toast.makeText(this, "No puedo salvar: "+fileName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show());
                            //Log.e(TAG, "Unable to save file via REST.", exception));
        }
    }

    private void query() {
        if (mDriveServiceHelper != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Querying for files.");
            Toast.makeText(this, "Quering archivos: ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            mDriveServiceHelper.queryFiles()
                    .addOnSuccessListener(fileList -> {
                        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                        for (File file : fileList.getFiles()) {
                            builder.append(file.getName()).append("\n");
                        }
                        String fileNames = builder.toString();

                        mFileTitleEditText.setText("File List");
                        mDocContentEditText.setText(fileNames);

                        setReadOnlyMode();
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(exception ->
                            Toast.makeText(this, "No puedo hacer query: ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show());
                            //Log.e(TAG, "Unable to query files.", exception));
        }
    }

    private void setReadOnlyMode() {
        mFileTitleEditText.setEnabled(false);
        mDocContentEditText.setEnabled(false);
        mOpenFileId = null;
    }

    private void setReadWriteMode(String fileId) {
        mFileTitleEditText.setEnabled(true);
        mDocContentEditText.setEnabled(true);
        mOpenFileId = fileId;
    }
}

DriveServiceHelper.java
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.OpenableColumns;
import androidx.core.util.Pair;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Tasks;
import com.google.api.client.http.ByteArrayContent;
import com.google.api.services.drive.Drive;
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.File;
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.FileList;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.concurrent.Executor;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class DriveServiceHelper {
    private final Executor mExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    private final Drive mDriveService;

    public DriveServiceHelper(Drive driveService) {
        mDriveService = driveService;
    }

    public Task<String> createFile() {
        return Tasks.call(mExecutor, () -> {
            File metadata = new File()
                    .setParents(Collections.singletonList("root"))
                    .setMimeType("text/plain")
                    .setName("Untitled file");

            File googleFile = mDriveService.files().create(metadata).execute();
            if (googleFile == null) {
                throw new IOException("Null result when requesting file creation.");
            }

            return googleFile.getId();
        });
    }

    public Task<Pair<String, String>> readFile(String fileId) {
        return Tasks.call(mExecutor, () -> {
            // Retrieve the metadata as a File object.
            File metadata = mDriveService.files().get(fileId).execute();
            String name = metadata.getName();

            // Stream the file contents to a String.
            try (InputStream is = mDriveService.files().get(fileId).executeMediaAsInputStream();
                 BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is))) {
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                String line;

                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringBuilder.append(line);
                }
                String contents = stringBuilder.toString();

                return Pair.create(name, contents);
            }
        });
    }

    public Task<Void> saveFile(String fileId, String name, String content) {
        return Tasks.call(mExecutor, () -> {
            File metadata = new File().setName(name);

            ByteArrayContent contentStream = ByteArrayContent.fromString("text/plain", content);

            mDriveService.files().update(fileId, metadata, contentStream).execute();
            return null;
        });
    }

    public Task<FileList> queryFiles() {
        return Tasks.call(mExecutor, () ->
                mDriveService.files().list().setSpaces("drive").execute());
    }

    public Intent createFilePickerIntent() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        intent.setType("text/plain");

        return intent;
    }

    public Task<Pair<String, String>> openFileUsingStorageAccessFramework(
            ContentResolver contentResolver, Uri uri) {
        return Tasks.call(mExecutor, () -> {
            // Retrieve the document's display name from its metadata.
            String name;
            try (Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(uri, null, null, null, null)) {
                if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    int nameIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME);
                    name = cursor.getString(nameIndex);
                } else {
                    throw new IOException("Empty cursor returned for file.");
                }
            }

            // Read the document's contents as a String.
            String content;
            try (InputStream is = contentResolver.openInputStream(uri);
                 BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is))) {
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringBuilder.append(line);
                }
                content = stringBuilder.toString();
            }
            return Pair.create(name, content);
        });
    }
}

